# explain the usages of "volatile" in java?

Tags: java, volatile

I'm learning the "volatile" keyword in Java. But I don't know how to use it appropriatly. And I have found some usages in JDK. Can you explain to me why using volatile ?

1)  class `HashMap` : `transient volatile int modCount;`?

I think this one is because of the visibilty, once the map is changed by other one thread, others thread can see the change. right ?

2) Inner static class `HashEntry` in `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
final K key;
final int hash;
volatile V value;
```

Why the value using volatile ?

3) class `AtomicInteger` : `private volatile int value;`?

4) class `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
private volatile long  keepAliveTime;
private volatile int   corePoolSize;
private volatile int   maximumPoolSize;
```

Is all because of the visibilty ? Or some other deeper reasons ?

Comment: Do you need anything more than visibility? It surely motivates all your examples.

Comment: volatile offers 2 guarantees: visibility, and atomicity of assignment, even for 64-bits types (double and long). So it's used for one or the other, or both.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and the reordering ?

Comment: I was about to mention reordering, but since it is mosty implied by visibility, I didn't. But now that you did, I wonder what exactly you think you need to ask the SO community about.

Answer (score 2):

Volatile is used when you want to make something accessible for modification to multiple threads. It marks the variable to be non-locally-cache-able for any thread. All reads and writes are from memory for all your threads.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile keyword in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz3FER8Hvj8